# Excel - Formula for measuring numeric change per quarter

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to set up a formula that measures numeric change per quarter.

So if `Q4` if blank then `Q3-Q2` etc.

The formula I have is

```
IF(F2>="0",F2-E2, IF(F2="",E2-D2, IF(E2="",D2-C2, IF(D2="",C2,""))))
```

But this only seems to work for `E2-D2`

Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: Please add some sample data so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

can you be a little more specific?
Where are your changing data? What data go in which column?
At a guess, Column C may represent Q1, D = Q2, E = Q3, F = Q4.
Now, where do you wish to insert the formula?
Why do you test for character values - e.g. "0" if the cells should contain numbers?
So, let me guess you want to calculate the difference between the last successive quarters where the higher column has a positive value. Correct?

If that's true, try this formula into G2 and drag it down the depth of the table:
=if(isnumber(F2),F2-E2,if(isnumber(E2),E2-D2,if(isnumber(D2),D2-C2,C2))))